# What is the best way to create send ports, receive locations, and Parties in Biztalk with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, biztalk

What is the best way to create send ports, receive locations, and Parties in Biztalk with Powershell? Note I want to do this do an existing environment. I seen people talk about the PSDrive. I just want to know the best way. Also I am a beginner in Powershell.I started out with this but now I am wondering if I am going about it the right way.

```bsh
#make sure the ExplorerOM assembly is loaded
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadwithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")

#Connect to the BizTalk management database
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = "sqlserever\instance; DATABASE = BizTalkMgmtDb; Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

but I get this error:

> Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Keyword not supported:

Comment: Shouldn't you have `SERVER=sqlserver\instance` or `INSTANCE=sqlserver\instance` instead of just the bare string?

Comment: right I added SERVER=mysqlserver\instance but still get an error

Comment: You probably want to escape your backslash.  e.g  SERVER=mysqlserver\\instance

Comment: I still get the same error: Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Keyword not supported: 'sql\\instance; database'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Catalog.ConnectionString = "sql\\instance; DATABASE=Biz ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: Looks like you were correct  "@MathiasR.Jessen" I misunderstood what you meant. This did work: $Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER=sql\instance; DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb; Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: How do I mark this part as answered?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can see the applications in my catalog and add send ports and Receive locations to those applications?